# Solr - facet.pivot.mincount=0 crashes server

Tags: solr

I am using Solr 7.3.0 (with pySolr) to search products in my database, returning products, facets and facet.pivots:

```
result = solr.search(query_s, **{
    'rows': '24', 
    'sort': formatted_sort, 
    'facet': 'on', 
    'facet.limit': '-1', 
    'facet.mincount': '1', 
    'facet.field': ['gender', 'material'],
    'facet.pivot': 'brand,series', 
    'fq': '-in_stock: 77'
})
```

The query_s selects specific fields, for example: `brand:Target AND gender:Men's`.

When I add `'facet.pivot.mincount': '0'` to the query, my Solr server crashes.

I have confirmed this behavior using a URL, so it isn't a pySolr issue.

What could be the cause for this strange behaviour?

**Edit**

I am using single cluster mode (not Solr Cloud).

Comment: what solr version are you using ?

Comment: 7.3.0 undistributed mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue and there is a issue open for this.
check here
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-6329

also seems like using minCount=0 processes excessive docs unneccessarily and uses too much memory which might explain crashing the nodes.

Check this jira
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-11711

Comment: Solr v. 7.3.0. I am not using Cloud (distributed) mode.

Comment: So you have a single node cluster ?

Comment: As far as I am aware.

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-11711 Check this. this might explain why mincount=0 is using too much memory and node is crashing. the jira is for distributed but i think the same concept applies and might explain your scenario.